# Excel VBA CountIF function Not Counting Values in Data Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to count all the values in a table column with the same name ID. Most values are number codes but a few have text, so all values in the column are formatted as text. The reference table (stored on a separate sheet within the same workbook) looks something like:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1564855 | 2 |
| 4956825H | 7 |
| 6495235 | 4 |

etc....

My code block looks like:

```
tablerange = Worksheets("tablesheet").ListObjects("table").ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
nametofind = Range("S2")          'also formatted as text

Range("T2") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tablerange, nametofind)
```

The function would count correctly when typed into a cell, but I can't seem to get it to work in VBA no matter what I try. The VBA Vlookup function works just fine with the same range and lookup value, but CountIF refuses to count up the values with these parameters.

I tried using operators and adding quotes around the variable. I tried substituting both text and numeric values. Also tried defining the variable as string. Nothing has worked yet.

Comment: How is `nametofind` declared?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Note use of `Set` when assigning the range

```vb
Dim tablerange As Range, nametofind As String, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("tablesheet")
Set tablerange = ws.ListObjects("table").ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange

With ActiveSheet 'for example
    nametofind = .Range("S2").Value          'also formatted as text
    .Range("T2").Value = Application.CountIf(tablerange, nametofind)
End With
```